# $X\sim f_{\theta}(x) = \frac{2}{3\theta}\left(1- \frac{x}{3\theta}\right)$, $0<x<3\theta$. Is $\bar{X}$ a sufficient estimator of $\theta$?

Tags: statistics

$X\sim f_{\theta}(x) = \frac{2}{3\theta}\left(1- \frac{x}{3\theta}\right)$, $0<x<3\theta$. Is $\bar{X}$ a sufficient estimator of $\theta$? Now I think this is probably not the case because for a given $\bar{X}$ there are many possible random samples that give this mean, however, the true mean $\theta$ still is important to finding the probability distribution of the $X_1\ldots X_n$. I can not however prove this... Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Neyman Factorization Theorem](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~pml1/proofs/main%2068.pdf): Given a sample $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, the joint pdf of our sample is is $f(x;\theta)=\left(\frac{2}{3\theta}\right)^n\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{x_i}{3\theta}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{3\theta}\right)^n\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{3\theta-x_i}{3\theta}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{9\theta^2}\right)^n\prod_{i=1}^n \left(3\theta-x_i\right)$

This cannot be factored to yield a function of the parameter and the mean, and another function of only the data, so the answer is no, the sample mean is not sufficient.